# How come the message which travels to Topic 2 via Topic 1 can have earlier broker timestamp than Topic 1 in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

Our Storm Topology is processing messages from Topic 1 and sending it to to Topic 2 and the message is having unique key and which is same in bot Topic 1 and Topic 2. We are trying to measure the actual latency by measuring the difference between the broker timestamp of of Topic 2 and the broker timestamp of of Topic 1 based on the unique key. Strangely some time for few messages it shows negative number not always though. How come the message which travels to Topic 2 via Topic 1 can have earlier broker timestamp than Topic 1. I have verified NTP between all the brokers in cluster 
and it is in synch.

Do anyone know and faced such kind of issue. We are using HDP 2.6.5 vesrion.

Comment: Have you verified NTP is the same between each broker?

Comment: Yes, I have verified NTP between all brokers in the cluster and it is in synch.

Comment: Can you show your topology code?

Comment: Topology code is actually reading message from topic 1 and processing it , which is taking around 50 to 60 milliseconds and sending that message again with some extra field to topic 2 . Even we have set messages time stamp equal to Kafka log append time while creating Kafka topic. So how the message time stamp of the message coming from topic 1 have earlier time stamp ? NTP between all broker is in .0001 millisecond. This is quite weird behaviour.

Comment: Is this within single machine?

Comment: Not within single machine, I mean if the lease of both of Kafka topics are same. If the leader are same then it does not give negative results but if leaders are different for the topics then it gives negative latency not always though. It is really weird behaviour.